# Is it possible to extract a cached excel query?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would like to extract the data in a query from an excel workbook.

- It's more than 1m rows and so cannot be turned into a worksheet
- We don't have access to the original data sources
- It reports the number of rows and can be used in a pivot table

Is it possible to save this data out to a csv directly from the Workbook Queries?

Comment: You said, it's larger Database so can't turned to Worksheet and not authorised to access the original Data source, in this situation how could you move further? Let me say the possibilities, 1. if records are in workbook then Export it to Access and work with 'Make Table Query' and finally Import to Excel for next steps. 2. If it's CSV file then  it can be converted into Excel. Please confirm the ORIGINAL Status of the file help me & others to find the best method.

Comment: If you are looking to extract Datasource & Query from Pivot Table, then I can suggest you the Macro.

Comment: The file is an `xlsx`, it's used in a pivot table and has a note saying how many records are loaded, so I know the data is there somewhere.

I've got a reference to the query in VBA, but it doens't seem helpful. See the documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/3c698446-813c-edc2-f8c9-66f5dfc2d1c3%28office.15%29.aspx

Comment: LEt me check the link soon I'll return to you.